# How to lock/freeze the grand total in a matrix in Power BI paginated report developed in reprot builder

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a Power Bi paginated report developed in Power BI report builder as shown below

[image]

This is a collapsable matrix report. When the view is collapsed, we can see the totals. However, when the view ix expanded, the totals go to the bottom as shown in the next picture

[image]

What I would like is that when the user scrolls down or expands the view, the grand total at the bottom should always show and is frozen like we can see in excel or standard power bi report.

Can someone please tell me how to freeze or lock the grand totals at the bottom of the rows so that they are always showing up when a user scrolls down or expands the view?