# how to freeze the row headers in collapsable matrix in Power BI paginated report

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, powerbi-paginated-reports

In a normal matrix in Power BI, If you go to the properties of the matrix and check the Fixed row header, then it will freeze the row header if you scroll to the right of the matrix. However, I have found that if you have a collapsable matrix row header, then this property will not work. For example check the below matrix

[image]

I have checked the below two properties to lock the row and column headers

[image]

The column headers are not collapsable so they seem to work. However, the row headers don't seem to freeze when scrolling to the right.

Can someone please give a suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lock/freeze the grand total in a matrix in Power BI paginated report developed in reprot builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75417102/how-to-lock-freeze-the-grand-total-in-a-matrix-in-power-bi-paginated-report-deve)

Comment: No sorry, it does not answer. There are ways to freeze the rows and columns headers which I have achieved. All that is left now is to also freeze the totals